# How to slice to a particular element in a Vec?

Tags: rust, vector

What is the best way to slice a `Vec` to the first occurrence of a particular element?

A naive method demonstrating what I want to do:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let to_num = 5;
    let mut idx = 0;
    for x in &v {
        if x != &to_num {
            idx += 1
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    let slice = &v[..idx];
    println!("{:?}", slice); //prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

[^ on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=737001fdaca3dda936233f3e5852fe45)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<[T]>::split()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split):

```rust
let slice = v.split(|x| *x == to_num).next().unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c17e62b03a67aaa2631518e9ae7d9c0).